# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '%,' to data type int

Tags: sql-server

Below are my tables - my master table `Gmaster` and child table `Tmaster`:

```
create table dbo.GMaster
(
    CourseId char(2),
    CourseName char(3)
);

create table dbo.TMaster
(
    ROLLNO char(5),
    NAME varchar(10),
    ADDRESS varchar(20),
    Course varchar(100)
);

insert into dbo.GMaster 
values ('-1',  'All'),
       ('0',  '' ,'' ),
       ('1',  'A','D'),
       ('3',  'Unassigned',''),
       ('4',  'C','')
       ('7',  'p','s'),

insert into dbo.TMaster 
values ('1', 'RAM', 'RAM ADDRESS', '0'),                      
       ('3', 'HARI', 'HARI ADDRESS', ',1,4'),                         
       ('4', 'JEFF', 'JEFF ADDRESS', '-1'),                   
       ('6', 'DAISY', 'DAISY ADDRESS', ',7');
       ('8', 'Flow', 'Chart', ',3');
```

This is my expected output:

| ROLLNO | NAME | ADDRESS | Course |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | RAM | RAM ADDRESS | Empty value |
| 3 | HARI | HARI ADDRESS | 'AD','C' |
| 4 | JEFF | JEFF ADDRESS | '','AD','Unassigned','C','PS' |
| 6 | DAISY | DAISY ADDRESS | 'PS' |
| 8 | Flow | Flow Chart | 'Unassigned' |

I tried this code but get an error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '%,' to data type int

```
select 
    SM.ROLLNO,
    SM.NAME, 
    SM.ADDRESS,
    (select 
         ',' + CM.CourseName
     from 
         dbo.GMaster as CM
     where 
         ',' + SM.Course + ',' like '%,' + CM.CourseId + ',%'
     for xml path(''), type).value('substring(text()[1], 2)', 'varchar(max)') as Course
from 
    dbo.[TMaster] as SM;
```

Comment: CM.CourseId is probably int. change it to: CAST(CM.CourseId AS NVARCHAR(MAX))

Comment: Any simple query to fetch the sample output other than the above one is also appreciated

Comment: now getting Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ',' to data type int.

Comment: CAST(SM.Course AS NVARCHAR(MAX))

Comment: still getting Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ',' to data type int.

Comment: `CONCAT(',', CM.CourseName)` might be a better™ choice.

Comment: I really suggest fixing your design though and normalising your data.

Comment: Can you please share the query for my expected result

Comment: can anyone answer this

Comment: What does your code really look like? SQL Server should not even be executing this to get a conversion error because you're trying to insert 3 columns' worth of values into `dbo.GMaster` which only has two columns defined. Even then you're missing a `,` delimiting a set of values and finish the set of values with a `,` instead of a `;`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `CREATE TABLE` script has a bunch of errors: commas in the wrong places, incorrect data types and lengths, missing columns.

**You really, really need to fix your design.** Denormalized tables are hard to work with.

Having said that, you can just split out the values using `STRING_SPLIT`, join to `GMaster`, then re-aggregate using `STRING_AGG`, all in a subquery.

You need some extra logic for the `All` case: you need to join all rows, but the `All` row itself should never be joined.

```sql
SELECT t.*, 
  Course = (
    SELECT STRING_AGG('''' + g.CourseName + '''', ',')
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(t.Course, ',') s
    JOIN dbo.GMaster g ON (
        g.CourseId = s.value OR
        s.value = '-1')
      AND g.CourseId <> '-1'
  )
FROM dbo.TMaster t;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/Crkx_dUk)

Comment: But for ',7' and ',3' i need to get only unassigned and PS but i am getting unassigned,unassigned and unassigned,ps instead i should get only one unassigned and only ps. This is happening only for the records which have ,first

Comment: can you provide me an update

Comment: It works in the fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/Crkx_dUk if your code is different the please share a link